# PowerShell ISE how to automate new tab creation with ScriptBlock closures?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

I'm trying to automate creation of a bunch of tabs in PowerShell ISE

I've started with a function such as

```
function Start-NewTab($name, [ScriptBlock]$scriptBlock)
{
    $tab = $psISE.PowerShellTabs.Add()
    $tab.DisplayName = $name
    sleep 2
    $tab.Invoke($scriptBlock)
}
```

however when I run it like so

```
$v = "hello world"
Start-NewTab "Test" { $v }
```

`hello world` isn't shown, unlike the following fragement

```
function Test-ScriptBlock([ScriptBlock]$sb) { & $sb }
Test-ScriptBlock { $v }
```

What's going on here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A "Tab" container is equated to a runspace (or [powershell execution environment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819494.aspx)) in the ISE. Since you are creating a new Tab (i.e. powershell execution environment) the variable v is undefined in that execution environment. The scriptblock is evaluated in the new execution environment and outputs the value of v (nothing).

It's easy to see how variable resolutions differs in the case of Test-Scriptblock from the case of Start-NewTab if you try to get the variable in the scriptblock by explicitly mentioning the scope where the variable should be found.

```
PS>Test-ScriptBlock { get-variable v -scope 0}
Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with name 'v'.
PS>Test-ScriptBlock { get-variable v -scope 1}
Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with name 'v'.
PS>Test-ScriptBlock { get-variable v -scope 2} # Variable found in grandparent scope (global in the same execution environment)
Name                           Value                                                                                                                           
----                           -----                                                                                                                           
v                              hello world

PS>Start-NewTab "Test" { get-variable v -scope 0 } # global scope of new execution environment
Get-Variable : Cannot find a variable with name 'v'.
PS>Start-NewTab "Test" { get-variable v -scope 1 } # proof that scope 0 = global scope
Get-Variable : The scope number '1' exceeds the number of active scopes.
```

One workaround for your problem is to define your variable in the scriptblock:

```
Start-NewTab "Test" { $v = "hello world";$v }
```

**Edit:** One more thing, your title mentions 'closure'. Scriptblocks in Powershell are not closures, however you can create a closure from a scriptblock. This won't help you with the problem you describe, though.

**Edit2:** Another workaround:

```
$v = "hello world"
Invoke-Expression "`$script = { '$v' }"
Start-NewTab "test" $script
```

Comment: How does this help, if I could create the data needed in the scriptblock, I wouldn't need to use a variable

Comment: I'm not sure what the restrictions for your particular problem are, however I've updated my post with another workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, however I have recently found a new work-around for this problem. It may be useful to somebody.

**Use an environmental variable:**

```
function Start-NewTab($name, [ScriptBlock]$scriptBlock)
{
    $tab = $psISE.PowerShellTabs.Add()
    $tab.DisplayName = $name
    sleep 2
    $tab.Invoke($scriptBlock)
}

$env:v = "hello world"
Start-NewTab "Test" { $env:v }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply create the scriptblock first.

```
$v={"Hello world"}                                                                                                    
start-newtab "test" $v
```

But you have to keep scope in mind.

Comment: His function is valid, all he needs to do is pass the right object. All I was showing that if he passes the correct values, Start-NewTab works. But I think the real issue here is creating the scriptblock initially from variables in the current PowerShell session.

Comment: @ScottWeinstein Creating the script block first works. Definitely looks like a scope issue. The variable v is null inside the function when it has been defined outside of the scriptblock.

Comment: @AndyArismendi It's not really a scoping issue (`$v` is evaluated in a new execution environment). This can be demonstrated, though, by explicitly mentioning the scope when fetching the variable. See my answer.